# Sending string across network with as3 on mobile?

Tags: android, flash, actionscript-3, send

Is there anyone there who can tell me how i can send a string ("example") to an ipadress on a local network via wifi in as3 on air on adroid.

Thanks in advance!

FlashCreated

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine you can just use the HTTPService class or URLRequest (if you're not using Flex) the code would be something like this:

```
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://192.168.1.100/test.php");

var urlVariables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();

urlVariables.testVarName = "example";
urlRequest.data = urlVariables;

sendToUrl(urlRequest);
```

alternatively if you want to listen to the response use a URLLoader, if you're going with Flex HTTPService basically wraps up this functionality into a single class for that just create one set the url and call myHTTPService.send([optional params if not on data]);

Let me know if this doesn't work out and what errors you get or behavior, haven't actually tried yet within an Android device but if there's variance in the approach I'd like to know as well.

Comment: So php file is resident on the computer your sending the mesange to?

Comment: @FlashCreated Yah I just assumed PHP could be whatever sort of server running there waiting to get the connection.  Assuming though that the PHP server is running from the lap/desktop you're sending to.

Comment: You need Apache web server installed and the document root in the Apache install/conf/httpd.conf then restart Apache check out wamp or lamp on Google for an installer.

Comment: Well without knowing any sort of Java network programming or other network programming... and even so, yes I believe this is going to be the simplest way I mean what are you trying to do with the data once it gets to a computer I imagine something more than show it on screen, if so you're going to need to program something more complicated on that end anyhow.  Without using a server you need to write one basically check out "Java Sockets" on google for how to access low level network connections in Java or else use BlazeDS for AMF -> Serialized Plain old Java Objects.

Comment: The flash code is all above and is simple anyhow, how are you expecting to "consume" or "digest" the message on the desktop? like what will it do in the end.

Comment: i just need to get a string from a android device (runing air flash) to a vb6 program on a desktop pc. I don't need the pc to reply. what is the simplest way???

Answer (score 0):

So php file is resident on the computer your sending the mesange to?